# How do I extract Ints from strings at specific indexes?

Tags: c++, string, integer

I'm currently working on an assignment. Where I need to take a string, read the value at index 1 and use that value to assign a value to an integer.

```
    int main()  
{
   string num;
   cin>> num;
   int readval;
   readval= num.at(0);
   cout << readval;
}
```

the problem is whenever I print readval its never the number at the index location that i specified. for example if I wanted num.at(0)= 4 from a string like 4 1 2 3 4. I want readval to be equal to that number (in this case 4) but when I print readval it prints 52 instead of what the value is in the index. I know that 52 is the ASCII code for 4 but I don't know why its not working for me

Comment: You're almost there. As you've noticed, when you turn a `char` directly into a number, you get the encoded value of that character. To get a digit as a number, you need to convert it from the character encoding by subtracting the encoding value of character 0 (48 in ASCII). Eg `readval= num.at(0) - '0';`. The value of character 4 minus the value of character 0 will for all encodings allowed by C++, always be 4

Comment: Being a string, `num` contains only the character code values of the character representations of the digits --- '4', not 4. You need to convert the character representation to an actual integer value.

Answer (score 2):

In your code the overload of the `<<` operator taking `int` is used. This prints the value as an integral number instead of printing the character.

If you want to print the character, just change the type of `readval` to `char`

```
char readval = num.at(0);
cout << readval;
```

If you want to work with an `int`, you can use the fact that the chars for the decimal digits are "next to each other" in the ascii table in ascending order.

```
int readval = num.at(0) - '0';
cout << readval;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()  
{
   string num;
   cin>> num;
   int readval;
   readval= num.at(0);
   cout << readval - 48;
}
```

Comment: You've to subtract the ASCII of  zero(48) to get the digit.

Comment: This assumes that we use ASCII. `readval - '0'` works even in the (admittedly rare) case of non-ASCII encoding.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: Right idea, but poor execution.